# Facebook does not ask for user_birthday permission

Tags: ios, facebook

In my app I ask user to grant permission for `user_birthday`. However when user authorizes the app Facebook does not mention user's birthday among other requested permissions. Do I have to get my app to review first and only then I may ask for `user_birthday`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to go through Login Review, or you have to add users to the App roles (Admin, Developer, Tester, ...). More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

There should actually be a very visible warning when you authorize as App Admin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit your app for review with valid reason to get user_birthday. according to [document  - developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

```
If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

When submitting for review, please be clear as to why age_range is not sufficient for your use case.
```